# What do you call a person who counts the favor he has done for you?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

Sometimes he/she rubs it in your face. What do you call the instance of this action? What do you call this action?

Comment: Hannibal Lecter? "Quid pro quo, Clarice." I think a quid pro quo kinda fits the behavior, but I don't think think theres a term for "quid-pro-quo-er"

Comment: @TheMadDeveloper - nice cultural reference! But I think "quid pro quo" is a more neutral term, more like "I'll scratch your back if you scratch mine", whereas the way I interpret the OP's question is that the person uses their magnanimity manipulatively or aggressively.

Comment: @Chappo - Good point. I suppose it's the psychopath in my reference that lent a tinge of malice to it.

Comment: A [*scorekeeper*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scorekeeper)

Comment: There's a difference between keeping an accurate tally or count of what you're owed, and rubbing it in someone's face when that person owes you something. You don't need to rub it in someone's face if you know exactly what you are owed. Constantly mocking and nagging doesn't require keeping an accurate count (and is often easier if you exaggerate how much you are owed).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes we say "He keeps score of all the nice things we do for each other," so you might could call him a scorekeeper or call the activity "scorekeeping/keeping score."

Other adjectives you might try to describe the person:

- shrewd
- calculating
- unforgiving
- cunning

Comment: **calculating** fits pretty well I think.

Comment: In fact, **calculating** fits very well as it's a good name for the characteristic but also, in this case, the person is literally counting, ie calculating, favours that you might owe them.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the adjective "unmagnanimous". Whilst not exactly what you're looking for it could work in the context you describe.

http://www.yourdictionary.com/unmagnanimous

It's an antonym for "magnanimous", which can be described as follows:

**magnanimous** |maɡˈnanəməs|

**adjective** -very generous or forgiving, especially toward a rival or someone less powerful than oneself.

Comment: I don't think this is a helpful answer. Not only does "unmagnanimous" fail to describe the particular situation where a person uses their magnanimity as a weapon, but the word "unmagnanimous" itself is extremely rarely used. As a comparison, [it's used about 20 times *less* than "yclept"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unmagnanimous%2Cyclept&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunmagnanimous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyclept%3B%2Cc0).